# Dynamic HTML street address box

Tags: javascript, html

Many times we need to ask customers where to ship their order. The customer can live anywhere in the world, so hard-coding a street address, state, and country box is not practical. Is there any javascript library out there which will update the `States` select box to relevant options when a different country is selected?

For example, for the U.S. we have 50 states, but when the user chooses a different country, the States select box should update to different options (e.g. if they choose Germany, it should show the 16 German states instead).

UPDATE:
I found [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/countries/), but it doesn't have country codes (e.g. for United States, the option value should be `US`).